# What's so special about the .call() function?

Tags: interfaces

All that the docs have to say about it is that it "lets the Ethereum network know we're not intending to persist any changes." So I get that it's used when not conducting a transaction.

So, I decided to test this:

```
truffle(development)> gc.then(function(instance){return instance.returnGreeting.call()})
'Hello, Joe'
truffle(development)> gc.then(function(instance){return instance.changeGreeting.call('threes a charm')})
[]
```

I thought it needed gas in the latter, so I tried but respectively got

```
truffle(development)> gc.then(function(instance){return instance.call.gas(10000)(bytes4(sha3("changeGreeting(string)")),'threes a charm')})
TypeError: Cannot read property 'gas' of undefined
```

But then I noticed that the following methods returned the same value, with no apparent difference.

```
truffle(development)> gc.then(function(instance){return instance.returnGreeting()})
'testing444'
truffle(development)> gc.then(function(instance){return instance.returnGreeting.call()})
'testing444'
```

To me, it's as useful as adding the keyword `public` to functions or fields: **It only has semantic value.** Where's the utility behind it?